# How to hide overflowing text when using pseudo elements (:before & :after)?

Tags: html, css, tabs, css-transforms

I am working on an advanced style for an angled tab that sits on a content div.

I have just about solved it, following create suggestions to follow :before and :after to shape the div. However, I am stuck trying to get the div itself to use max-width instead of width:

HTML

```
<br>
<div class="tab">Really really really really really really long content title</div>
<div class="tab-content">Content text</div>
```

CSS

.

```
tab-content, .tab, .tab:before, .tab:after {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
body {
    background-color: #666;
}
.tab-content {
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.tab:before {
}
.tab {
    max-width: 150px;
    display:block;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 15px 100px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100000000;
    line-height:50px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.tab:after {
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 00px;
    display: block;
    content:" ";
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    top: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -28px;
    transform:skewX(45deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:skewX(45deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Any ideas?

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/robmc/ZvEyx/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not too particular about semantics, you could try:

```
<div class="tab"><div>Really really really really really...</div></div>
```

and add the following CSS rule:

```
.tab div {
    outline: 1px dotted blue; /* for demo only... */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: inherit;
}
```

the child `<div>` could be replaced by a header, which may help with SEO.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/dyCXT/

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set the text color to transparent on the `.tab`, and then use the `:first-line` pseudo element to only set the text on the first line to have a color.

```
.tab {
    color: transparent;
}
.tab:first-line
{
    color: #000;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvEyx/11/)</kbd>

**Edit**

I have had a bit of a tinker with it and I think an even nicer solution is to set the `font-size` and `line-height` on `.tab` to `0px`. And then just set them to whatever you like using the `:first-line` pseudo element. This way the  invisible lines won't become visible when text is selected (which is an issue with my original answer).

```
.tab:first-line {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.tab {
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvEyx/12/)</kbd> for this approach.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately then I lose the styling I created on tab:after. Do you know of any way other way I can resize it? Have I got the position: tags wrong? I can't see an easy way from here though.

Comment: Although this is clever, my only hesitation is that a search engine may flat `font-size: 0px` as an attempt to inject spam in the content.  However, if this tab were part of a password protected area, then it would not matter.